# [Python]: sorting defaultdict's values

Tags: python, sorting, defaultdict

I want to sort values in defaultdict's item according to their time period.
How can I sort them?

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d['Mon'].append("10:00-24:00")
d['Tue'].append("12:00-14:00")
d['Mon'].append("1:35-4:00")
for i in d.items():
    print i
```

if I do this above I would get:

```
('Mon', ['10:00-24:00', '1:35-4:00'])
('Tue', ['12:00-14:00'])
```

How can I sort the values in the defaultdict according to the time order, so I can have:

```
('Mon', ['1:35-4:00','10:00-24:00'])
('Tue', ['12:00-14:00'])
```

Comment: Convert the strings to, say, tuples of two `datetime` objects before appending to the lists.

Comment: Your strings are not a single time. It's not clear how you want to sort them. Additionally, your question is Too Broad. You have two separate questions: 1. How do you sort a list stored as a value in a `dict` (answer: the same wya you sort any other list). 2. How do you sort time ranges, which is unanswerable because you haven't specified by what logic you want to sort them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your times should be in a format that is easier to sort. As you have it now `'10:00'` is lexicographical smaller than
`'1:35'`, which is not what you want. One way to fix this is to add leading zeros to times in the single-digit hours.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d['Mon'].append("10:00-24:00")
d['Tue'].append("12:00-14:00")
d['Mon'].append("01:35-04:00")

for i in d.items(): i[1].sort()

>>> print d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Mon': ['01:35-04:00', '10:00-24:00'], 'Tue': ['12:00-14:00']})
```

If you need to convert your time strings automatically you could do a regex replace:

```
t = '1:35-4:00'
t = re.sub(r'(^|-)(\d:\d\d)', r'\g<1>0\2', t)
>>> print t
'01:35-04:00'
```

Also check out DYZ's solution which converts your strings to datetime tuples. He also points out that '24:00' is not a valid time, and you could take care of those with `t = t.replace('24:', '00:')`.

Comment: You're welcome! I updated with a method to add leading zeros automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the values as time ranges by time before printing them. The following function converts your string to a tuple of two `time` objects:

```
def str2timerange(timestring):
    timestring = timestring.replace("24:00", "00:00")
    return [datetime.time(*map(int, t.split(":"))) for t in timestring.split("-")]
```

Remember that "24:00" is not a valid time, it must be recorded as "00:00".

```
d = defaultdict(list)
d['Mon'].append("10:00-24:00") # WRONG, but str2timerange will fix it
d['Tue'].append("12:00-14:00")
d['Mon'].append("1:35-4:00")
for i in d.items():
    print(i[0],sorted(i[1],key=str2timerange))

#Mon ['1:35-4:00', '10:00-24:00']
#Tue ['12:00-14:00']
```